# Android application control flow?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am very new to Android application development. Just started Hello world android application yesterday.

I was wondering whether there will be any control flow in the android application, like the Struts MVC, Spring MVC etc. has in them.

I am working on enhancing the android application, so I thought that knowing the flow of control would be a good start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following three materials will be very good for you if you'd like to know the control flow of an Android application:

**Application Fundamentals**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

**Activity**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

**Task and Back Stack**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 2):

[image: The below flow explain about android application execution flow.]

1. All resource files are combined together by AAP[Android Asset Packing Tool].
   Resource files are like audio video images other asset related files.
   2.Java files converted into .class files by JVM.So, the out of the jvm will be .class files, that are heavy weight to put into android. So, that one more level of process will be taken place.
2. So, the .Class files are entered as input to DX tool. Basically, this is a tool which will convert .class files to .dex files. That mean Dalvik executable file. Those files are eligible to execute on DVM (Dalvik Virtual Machine)
3. After getting .dex files, packed them APK builder. Which is basically, Application Packaging. So, this packed files kept into devices and that will be executed by DVM.

[image: Android Application Workflow]